# How to use require_once in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, class

I'm trying to include a PHP class in magento 2.

I use a require_once and create a folder lib in the root of my module and there I put the folder that contains the class `lib/Meli/Meli.php`

Also try in the project folder `lib/lib_web/Meli/Meli.php`

All without success, any suggestion

This is my controller `Controller/Adminhtml/Action/publicar.php`

```
<?php 
namespace Uno\MercadoLibre\Controller\Adminhtml\Action;

use \Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class publicar extends Action {
  protected $_session;

  protected $_filesystem;
  protected $_directoryList;

  /**
   * @param Action\Context $context
   */
  public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
  ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_session = $session;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function _isAllowed() {
      return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Uno_MercadoLibre::action_publicar');
  }

  /**
   * Publicar action
   *
   * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
   */
  public function execute() {
    $appId = '123';
    $secretKey = 'abcdefghijkl';
    $redirectURI = 'https://example.mx';
    $siteId = 'MLM';

    //$path = $this->_directoryList->getPath('lib_web');
    //echo "PATH " . $path.'/Meli/Meli.php';
    //require_once($path.'/Meli/Meli.php');

    //$libPath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::LIB)->getAbsolutePath();

    $mediapath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::APP)->getAbsolutePath();
    $modulePath = $mediapath.'code/Uno/MecadoLibre/lib/Meli/Meli.php';

    echo $modulePath;

    require_once($modulePath);

    $meli = new Meli($appId, $secretKey);
    $params = array();

    $url = '/sites/' . $siteId;

    $result = $meli->get($url, $params);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
  }
}

?>
```

my echo `$modulePath`, returns

```
/var/inetpub/example.mx/app/code/Uno/MecadoLibre/lib/Meli/Meli.php
```

but it does not help me for the require_once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, for your information, I told you how I resolved this.

In my class **`Meli.php`** add:

```
namespace Uno\MercadoLibre\Controller\Adminhtml\Action;
```

In my controller, add:

```
use \Uno\MercadoLibre\Lib\Meli\Meli;
```

Object Manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$ml_session = $ objectManager->create('\Uno\MercadoLibre\Lib\Meli\Meli', ['client_id' => $ appId, 'client_secret' => $ secretKey, 'access_token' => $ accessToken]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code to the path

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

    /**
     * @var DirectoryList
     */
    private $directoryList;

/**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param DirectoryList $directoryList
     */
    public function __construct(
        DirectoryList $directoryList
    )
    {
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
    }

$modulePath= $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::APP).'code/Uno/MecadoLibre/lib/Meli/Meli.php';
 require_once($modulePath);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: All right with the path, I have an error with the instance of the class

_PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Uno\\MercadoLibre\\Controlle\\Adminhtml\\Action\\Meli' not found_

It does not take into account my path _lib/Meli/Meli.php_

Comment: As per the error "Uncaught Error: Class 'Uno\\MercadoLibre\\Controlle\\Adminhtml\\Action\\Meli"
Your class name should be "Meli" and in your code, you have written "publicar ". I think this might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can try following solution:

```
private $googleClient;
private $directoryList;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList
)
{
    $this->directoryList = $directoryList;

    $this->getGoogleClient();
}


private function getGoogleClient()
{
    $dir = $this->directoryList->getRoot();
    require_once $dir . '/service/google-api-php-client-main/vendor/autoload.php';

    $this->googleClient = new \Google\Client();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Zend_Loader;

class GetPdfData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $dir;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->initializePDF();
    }

    /**
     * Construct initialization of mpdf library
     */
    protected function initializePDF()
    {
        error_reporting(0);

        $path = $this->dir->getRoot() . "/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/";

        $this->pdf = $path . 'Mpdf.php';

        //include_once $this->pdf;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pdf, null, true);

        $this->configvariables = $path . 'Config/ConfigVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->configvariables;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->configvariables, null, true);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Your Code";
        exit();
    }
}
```

**Note: Here we need to add absolute path of files which we want to include_once or require_once. MPdf is installing via composer require mpdf/mpdf command and this module placed into the vendor directory.**