# What is the replacement for 'require_once' in PHP for Magento2 to resolve CodeSniffer test issue in Magento store?

Tags: magento2, php

I'm a beginner at PHP and Magento have developed a Magento2 extension and used this line code in it:

```
require_once '/../knownuserv3/KnownUser.php';
```

But when I tried to put my extension in Magento Store, I got a series of test failure from Code Sniffer, which I solved all but for this one couldn't find any solution until now.
knownuser is a class in another library includes a static method which I need to call it.
this is the error text from Code Sniffer:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use require\_once in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/257722/how-to-use-require-once-in-magento-2)

Comment: No, it didn't work, I tried to use object manager and dependency injection but still I needed to use require_once to load the related class. I don't understand why shouldn't we use require_once and what is  the replacement for it?!

Comment: have you tried using `use vendor\module\classname;` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried this as well. but the problem is that the class that I'm using it is a third party library so it seems it doesn't load before using require!

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Zend_Loader;

class GetPdfData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList
     */
    protected $dir;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->initializePDF();
    }

    /**
     * Construct initialization of mpdf library
     */
    protected function initializePDF()
    {
        error_reporting(0);

        $path = $this->dir->getRoot() . "/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/";

        $this->pdf = $path . 'Mpdf.php';

        //include_once $this->pdf;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->pdf, null, true);

        $this->configvariables = $path . 'Config/ConfigVariables.php';

        // require_once $this->configvariables;
        Zend_Loader::loadFile($this->configvariables, null, true);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Your Code";
        exit();
    }
}
```

**Note: Here we need to add absolute path of files which we want to include_once or require_once. MPdf is installing via composer require mpdf/mpdf command and this module placed into the vendor directory.**